# Is $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \alpha w(t) e(\alpha (a_1t_1 + \dotsb + a_n t_n)) dt\,d \alpha = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, integration, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $a_i$ be a nonzero real number for each $1 \leq i \leq n$. $w$ a smooth nonnegative with compact support. I would like to understand the following integral.
$$
I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \alpha w(t) e(\alpha (a_1t_1 + \dotsb + a_n t_n)) dt\,d \alpha.
$$
If the factor $\alpha$ were not present in the integrand, then the contribution comes from where $\alpha = 0$, but with this additional factor, I was thinking that perhaps $I$ is $0$? or something with very small absolute value. Any comment or suggestions to estimate this integral would be appreciated!

PS. $e(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$.

Comment: The integral $d\alpha$ is evidently divergent.

Comment: I added a clarification thank u

Comment: I agree the integral $d\alpha$ diverges.  And the principal value $\lim_{K\to+\infty}\int_{-K}^K\cdots \,d\alpha$ still diverges except for some exceptional choices of $w$.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but does it diverge? Take for example $w(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n\theta(1-|t_k|)$, with $\theta$ the unit step function, then the integral equals $$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\alpha\, \alpha\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(2\pi a_k\alpha)}{\pi a_k\alpha}$$ which equal 0 for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Thank you for the many comments! as explained by @CarloBeenakker there is no convergence issue with $w$ compact support. another way is using $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} w(t) e(\alpha a t) dt \ll_N (\alpha a)^{-N}, $$ for any $N > 0$. The contribution from large $\alpha$ can then be bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asks whether the integral is 0, the answer is no in general. For example, let me take $n=2$, $a_1,a_2>0$, $w(t_1,t_2)=\theta(t_1)\theta(1-t_1)\theta(1-|t_2|)$, with $\theta(x)$ the unit step function. Then
$$I=\begin{cases}
\frac{i}{2\pi a_1a_2}&\text{if}\; a_1>a_2\\
0&\text{if}\; a_2>a_1.
\end{cases}
$$

---

Since there was some discussion in the comments, let me check the convergence of the integral:
$$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \alpha w(t) \exp\bigl(2\pi i\alpha (a_1t_1 + \cdots + a_n t_n)\bigr) \,d \alpha\prod_{k=1}^n dt_k $$
$$\qquad=-\frac{1}{2\pi ia_1}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{dw}{dt_1} \exp\bigl(2\pi i\alpha (a_1t_1 + \cdots + a_n t_n)\bigr) \,d \alpha\prod_{k=1}^n dt_k$$
$$\qquad=-\frac{1}{2\pi ia_1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{dw}{dt_1} \delta\bigl(a_1t_1 + \cdots + a_n t_n\bigr) \,\prod_{k=1}^n dt_k, $$
which converges when $w$ has a compact support.

Comment: Note that in your example $w$ is not "smooth"; it is not even continuous.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar -- indeed, here's a continuous example: $n=2$, $a_1=a_2=1$, $w(t_1,t_2)=\cos(\pi t_1/2)\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(t_1)\sin(\pi t_2)\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(t_2)$, which gives $I=\frac{1}{3}i/\pi$.

Comment: no absolute values around $t_1$ in the definition of $w$ is not a typo, correct?

Comment: it seems that $I=0$ depending on some choice of $w$. is there a way to see when we can expect  $I=0$?

Comment: no typo's I think, the first example can also be written as $w(t_1,t_2)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(t_1)\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(t_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Example for divergence.  $n=1$, $a_1=1$, $w(t) = \mathbf1_{[0,1]}(t)$.  Note $w$ is not "smooth"; it is not even continuous.

Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \alpha w(t) e(\alpha (a_1t_1 + \dotsb + a_n t_n)) dt
=\int_0^1(\alpha\exp(2\pi i(\alpha t))\;dt
=\frac{i}{2\pi}\big(1-e^{i 2 \pi \alpha}\big)
\\
\int_{-K}^K \frac{i}{2\pi}\big(1-e^{i 2 \pi \alpha}\big)\;d\alpha
=\frac{i}{2\pi^2}\big(2\pi K -\sin(2\pi K)\big)
\\
\lim_{K\to+\infty} \frac{i}{2\pi^2}\big(2\pi K -\sin(2\pi K)\big) = +i\infty
$$

---

According to Carlo's argment, we do have convergence when $w$ is $C^1$ with compact support.

Comment: note that larger $n$ cures the divergence; in this example, if I would take $w(t_1,t_2,\ldots t_n)=\prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(t_k)$ then $I=0$ for $n\geq 3$.